# apply changes to another branch git

Tags: git

this is my issue: I have 2 branch, master and deploy, I want work on master branch and on finish bring my changes to deploy branch and push it to remote repository.
I tried this way:

```
git branch deploy
```

now I have 2 branch, first commit on master branch:

```
git commit -a -m "first commit"
```

bring the changes to deploy repository:

```
git merge deploy
```

go to deploy branch:

```
git checkout deploy
```

push the changes:

```
git push origin deploy
```

but the merge command does not give me the expected result.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the expected result? and what is the actual result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of the workflow you put along the Git commands, it seems that you are using `git merge` in the reverse way.

Indeed, `git merge a-given-branch` basically means "**integrate `a-given-branch` into the current branch** (creating a merge commit if need be)".

Thus, your proposed workflow should read:

```
git branch deploy
```

now I have 2 branch, first commit on master branch:

```
git commit -a -m "first commit"
```

go to deploy branch and import the changes from master:

```
git checkout deploy
git merge master
```

push the changes to deploy repository:

```
git push origin deploy
```

For more details on the `git merge` command, see also the [online documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

Comment: An opinion, I think that the description "import the commits from..." will confuse things further, as that's not what happens. A merge is a commit which references two parent commits rather than one.

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox; admittedly my initial phrasing could be somewhat misleading. But on the other hand a `git merge` don't always lead to a merge commit (it can lead to a fast-forward merge). Anyway I rephrased the sentence at stake to make it clearer.